# Eclipse/ App Engine Page load failed with error: The network connection was lost

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I had a Google App Engine Standard Projects running in Eclipse in different workspaces without any problems for many weeks.

Suddenly, since today, I get an error when trying to Run any projects as an App Engine:

**http://localhost:8080/
Page load failed with error: The network connection was lost.**

I have no idea by what this was caused, as I was coding on a project during that time and a few hours ago still worked normally.

I do not get any other specific error in the Console, the processes seem to run normally at first. Any ideas that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I think for some reason the local preview in port 8080 is not available anymore, not sure if it changed its port, you can try restarting your OS and eclipse and launching the local server again. You can also Go to the servers tab in Eclipse and change the HTTP port there to something else like 9080 and try again with that new port.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the exact reason why it was caused, but my system seemed to have issues to resolve localhost. I used it with the IP instead and after some days it started working again using localhost.